# Get second maximum number only if highest one not available in SQL and not return null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My Table:

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>ProductCode</th>
    <th>year_numb</th>
    <th>month_numb</th>
    <th>qty_instock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>002792</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>002792</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>002792</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>000002</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>000002</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

SQL:

```
strSql1 = "SELECT qty_instock FROM StockMaster WHERE ProductCode = '" + strProdCode + "' AND month_numb = (SELECT MAX(month_numb) from StockMaster)"
```

This one only return values with the highest month_number which is '5' for this matter however '000002' only returns a null value. please give me a solution to display second highest number from month_number.

Needed output:

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>ProductCode</th>
    <th>year_numb</th>
    <th>month_numb</th>
    <th>qty_instock</th>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td>002792</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>000002</td>
    <td>2020</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to get max `qty_instock` for given `ProductCode`? For example, for `ProductCode = 002792` return `5`, and for `ProductCode = 000002` return `10`?

Comment: @lliarTurdushev Yes Exactly what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get max `qty_instock` for given product code `strProdCode` then you should use the next query:

```
select top 1 qty_instock
from StockMaster
where ProductCode = strProdCode
order by month_numb desc;
```

This query for `strProdCode = '002792'` returns value `4`, and for value `strProdCode = '000002'` returns `10`. Here is [complete sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93dc36/6) that demostrates this query.

As a side note, if you are going to use this query in you `C#` code then it is recommended to use parameters in SQL statemets instead of directly inlining values into the query. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/12833205) describes why it is important to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

***You can try below query to get the desired result -***

**Sample Table & Data**

```
Declare @Product table 
(ProductCode varchar(10), [Year] int, month_numb int, qty_instock int)

insert into  @Product
values
('002792',  2020  ,  4 ,  1 ),
('002792',  2020  ,  5 ,  1 ),
('000002',  2020  ,  3 ,  13),
('000002',  2020  ,  4 ,  5 )
```

**Query**

```
;With cte(ProductCode, [Year], month_numb )
as
(select ProductCode, [Year], max(month_numb) month_numb
from @Product p
group by ProductCode, [Year]
) 
select p.* from @Product p 
inner join cte on p.ProductCode = cte.ProductCode 
and p.Year = cte.Year
and p.month_numb = cte.month_numb
```